# Imbalanced fine-tuning of inception v3 network (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am doing fine-tuning on the pretrained on the Image-net Challenge, inception v3 network of tensorflow. In my classification problem I am using 2 classes because I want to understand if an image contains food or not. My dataset is imbalanced because I have a lot more images on the non-food class (which makes sense I think). When I apply fine-tuning, I have high accuracy on the non-food class and very low accuracy on the food class. Then I am cutting the last 2 inception modules and 2 layers are inserted: a new convolutional layer and a global average pooling layer (and then we have a softmax for output). I apply again a short fine-tuning on the newly introduced layers and now the network gives me high accuracy on the food class and very low accuracy on the non-food.

Any ideas of what might be happening?

Comment: Accuracy as a metric might be misleading. Is it ever just guessing the same thing every time?

Comment: By accuracy I mean: (number of rightly predicted food images) / (number of food images) and the same for non-food. In the first fine-tuning I have 8.78% for food and 97.72% for non-food but in the second fine-tuning(after cutting the network) I have 95.48% for food and 0.15% for non-food.

Comment: Have you tried balancing your training set?

Comment: Finally I had problem with my accuracy script but now it's right. I tried to balance the batches of training in each step, but now I think that the network is overfitted, because food class gives high accuracy and non-food accuracy is not balanced.